# Is it possible to group expanding rows in a PrimeNG table (Stackblitz examples included)?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

#### What I'm trying to achieve

I have a p-table with expandable rows, which I need to be able to group. The groups themselves do not need to be expandable and should always show all items within them. The rows within the groups should expand.

##### Stackblitz example

Here is a [janky solution with nested tables](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d4veb7-thuma4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-row-expand-demo.html) in Stackblitz which demonstrates the kind of thing I want to achieve (except that the columns don't line up and it should be all in one table so that sorting and filtering etc works as it should).

#### Where I've got to so far

I have been able to make a [table with expanding rows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d4veb7-fxnbrg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-row-expand-demo.html) and a [table with grouping](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d4veb7?file=package.json), but I just can't find a way to get both features to play nicely together since both [row expand](https://primeng.org/table#row-expand) and [row groups](https://primeng.org/table#expand) use the same `dataKey` and `ng-template "rowexpansion"`.

The [docs](https://primeng.org/table#expand) imply that row groups should not be treated as expandable unless `expandableRowGroups` is present, but this doesn't actually seem to be the case.

I feel like I'm going in circles here, and I can't find much about this online except for a tangentially related [five year old forum thread](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=51019) which is now just broken links.